# Meteorjs mongodb unique document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Having a difficult time testing for a document in mongodb. All this is done in `Meteor.isServer` (Meteor 1.1.0.2; MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7). Here's the document ("_id" is auto generated by mongo, and shortened here by me):

```
{ "_id" : "YLzNTSqP", "0" : { "name": "Goodrich", "id" : "c5216", "phone" : "555-1212", "address" : "500 Wave Road, City, St, 12345" }}
```

My insert is just this as the mongodb inserts the "_id" and the "0" and makes my insert the object of the "0":

```
db_insert = { "name": "Goodrich", "id" : "c5216", "phone" : "555-1212", "address" : "500 Wave Road, City, St, 12345" };
```

I'm trying to search on "id" (not "_id") to see if the document exists in the collection.

I've also created a unique index on "id" which isn't helping:

```
db.collectionName.ensureIndex({id:1},{unique:true})
```

I've tried numerous variations of (I've used the var for the id, as well as hardcoding in a value that I know is in the database).

`collectionName.find({id:"c5216"})`

`collectionName.find({"id":"c5216"})`

`collectionName.findOne({"id":"c5216"})`

etc. The result is typically `[object Object]`

I've tried setting that to a var, then

`if(var){`  or `if(var.size() > 0)` or `if(var.count())` which throws an error as it's an object rather an array, `if(var.hasNext())` isn't working either.

Should I not be testing for the existence prior to inserting as I don't want duplicate records/documents. Should I just insert (and since there's an unique index on the "id", mongo will delete the current document and insert the one the code's on? Do either of these have a performance hit?

Comment: Your problem is that your 'id' is inside the '0' object. How it got there is a mystery. 'name','phone','id' fields and so on should be on the same level as _id, instead they are inside this mysterious '0' object. Please show the exact code that inserts the db_insert object.

Comment: This question (checking for the existence of a document, if I understand correctly) has probably already been answered on SO and I am having a hard time finding where...

Comment: The '0:' means your doc is a nested array which probably happened by calling insert([doc]).  Please show the insert code.